# File processing via list of files in text document in batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to achieve some file control with batch processing.

The base idea is a text file is supplied which contains a list of files and folder paths.

What I then need to do is is move these names files to another location referencing the same folder structure. The folder paths also vary some can be 2 deep others up to 4.

The reason for batch is that it can be hundreds of files at a time thus making manual processing time consuming and hard.

An example of the text file input is:

```
copier\spc240\parts.cat\M095_M096_CHN_V1.05.pdf
copier\spc240\parts.cat\M095_M096_NA_V1.06.pdf
copier\spc240\parts.cat\M099_M100_NA_V1.10.pdf
copier\spc240\parts.cat\M100_CHN_V1.10.pdf
options\df3090\D779_21_V1.01.pdf
options\pb3190\D747_27_V1.00.pdf
```

Below is what I have managed to do so far:

```
@echo off
set "file=deletes.txt"
set /A i=0
for /F "usebackq delims=*" %%a in ("%file%") do (
set /A i+=1
call set array[%%i%%]=%%a
call set n=%%i%%
)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (
echo|set /p="move %%array[%%i]%% moved\%%array[%%i]%%">>Test.txt 
echo.>>Test.txt
)
echo pause>>Test.txt
rename Test.txt RunMe2Move.bat
pause
```

What this currently does for me is make a batch file that could be run seperately, however this is where I stumble down. This errors as the destination folders do not exist and I am not familiar enough with arrays in batch to split the text lines to enable me to use the mkdir for the missing folders or trim the file names.

In essence I am trying to get the following lines of code either processed or output (using copier\spc240\parts.cat\M095_M096_CHN_V1.05.pdf as example) for each line in the text file.

```
mkdir moved\copier\spc240\parts.cat\
move copier\spc240\parts.cat\M095_M096_CHN_V1.05.pdf moved\copier\spc240\parts.cat\
```

Ultimately I am trying to get all of this done in one file if possible, the output is just there so I can check things through.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%file%) do (
    SET "fpath=%%~a"
    SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
    SET "fpath=!fpath:%%~nxa=!"
    md "moved\!fpath!"
    move "%%~a" "moved\!fpath!"
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

Comment: thanks for that sending me down another road. This appears to do the whole file path is there a way to do it from where the file is located? As when I run this I get the moved folder but then an entire replica..eg 'Y:\TDC New Ver\TDC Jan Data\03\moved\TDC New Ver\TDC Jan Data\03\cloud\' instead of 'Y:\TDC New Ver\TDC Jan Data\03\moved\cloud'. The batch file is being run from the 03 folder currently.